infinite re-renders in real time text editor with next js and flask
I have built a real time rich text editor in next js and flask but the thing is once lets say user1 (U1) starts editing, in the browsers of u2 u3, as well as even u1 it keeps re rendering the whole thing repeatedly infinitely
for the editor components i have used editor.js
next js code ->
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { backendDomainHandler } from '@/generalConfig/BackendAndMiddlewareHelpers';
import { debounce, isEqual } from 'lodash';

const EditorJS = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/editorjs'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading editor...</p>
});

const Header = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/header'));
const ImageTool = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/image'));
const List = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/list'));
const LinkTool = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/link'));
const Table = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/table'));
const CodeTool = dynamic(() => import('@editorjs/code'));

const EditorComponent = ({ socketState }) => {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  const [editorData, setEditorData] = useState(() => {
    const savedData = localStorage.getItem('editorData');
    return savedData ? JSON.parse(savedData) : {};
  });

  const emitChange = debounce((data) => {
    socketState.emit("documentEdited", data);
  }, 800);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const initEditor = async () => {
      const [EditorJSModule, HeaderModule, ImageToolModule, ListModule, LinkToolModule, TableModule, CodeToolModule] = await Promise.all([
        import('@editorjs/editorjs'),
        import('@editorjs/header'),
        import('@editorjs/image'),
        import('@editorjs/list'),
        import('@editorjs/link'),
        import('@editorjs/table'),
        import('@editorjs/code')
      ]);

      if (!editorRef.current) {
        const editor = new EditorJSModule.default({
          holder: 'editorjs',
          tools: {
            header: HeaderModule.default,
            image: {
              class: ImageToolModule.default,
              config: {
                endpoints: {
                  byFile: `${backendDomainHandler()}/upload`, 
                }
              }
            },
            list: {
              class: ListModule.default,
              config: {
                defaultStyle: 'unordered'
              }
            },
            linkTool: LinkToolModule.default,
            table: TableModule.default,
            code: CodeToolModule.default,
          },
          data: editorData,
          placeholder: "Your beginning point, add lists, images, tables, links, code snippets and more...",
          onChange: async () => {
            const savedData = await editor.save();
            setEditorData(savedData);
            localStorage.setItem('editorData', JSON.stringify(savedData));
            emitChange(savedData);
          }
        });

        editorRef.current = editor;
      }
    };

    initEditor();

    return () => {
      if (editorRef.current) {
        editorRef.current.destroy();
        editorRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDocumentUpdate = async (data) => {
      if (editorRef.current) {
        await editorRef.current.isReady;
        editorRef.current.save().then((currentData) => {
          if (!isEqual(currentData, data)) {
            editorRef.current.blocks.clear().then(() => {
              editorRef.current.blocks.render(data);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };

    socketState.on("documentUpdated", handleDocumentUpdate);

    return () => {
      socketState.off("documentUpdated", handleDocumentUpdate);
    };
  }, [socketState]);

  return (
    <>
      <style jsx>{`
        #editorjs {
          padding: 2rem;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          min-width: 45.5rem;
          border-radius: 0.5rem;
        }
      `}</style>
      <div id="editorjs" className='max-h-[38rem] min-h-[5rem] overflow-y-auto'></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditorComponent;


at a second place where im using the editor component ->

const NotesComponet = () => {
  const EditorComponent = dynamic(() => import('../TextEditor'), {
    ssr: false
  });

  return (
    <Sheet>
      <SheetTrigger style={{
        position: "relative",
        top: "-1.2rem"
      }}>
        <Button style={{
          background: "black",
          color: "white"
        }} variant="roundedBorderBtn">Notes</Button>
      </SheetTrigger>
      <SheetContent side={"left"} className="!max-w-[50rem]">
        <SheetHeader>
          <SheetDescription>
            <div className='flex items-start gap-6 mt-7'>
              <EditorComponent socketState={socketState} />
            </div>
          </SheetDescription>
        </SheetHeader>
      </SheetContent>
    </Sheet>
  )
}

flask code ->

@socketio.on("documentEdited")
def handle_document_edited(data):
    logging.info(f"Document edited: {data}")
    emit("documentUpdated", data, broadcast=True, include_self=False)
    ```
    
can somebody please help me

